# Why gdb cast output truncated once input exceed int max?

Tags: gdb, long-long

Example of `p/x`:

```
(gdb)  p/x (long long)-2147483647 #still works
$1 = 0xffffffff80000001
(gdb) p/x (long long)-2147483648 #truncated once input exceed max int
$2 = 0x80000000
(gdb) p/x (long long)-2147483649
$3 = 0x7fffffff
(gdb) whatis $1
type = long long
(gdb) whatis $2
type = long long
(gdb) whatis $3
type = long long
```

And `p/u`:

```
(gdb) p/u (long long)-2147483647
$1 = 18446744071562067969
(gdb) p/u (long long)-2147483648
$2 = 2147483648
(gdb) whatis $1
type = long long
(gdb) whatis $2
type = long long
```

I always concluded that this is gdb bug, but now I think I may misunderstanding and decided to post this question here.

Output (as requested by comment):

```
(gdb) whatis -2147483647
type = int
(gdb) whatis -2147483648
type = unsigned int
(gdb) whatis -2147483648LL
type = long long
(gdb) p (long long)-2147483648LL
$1 = -2147483648
```

Comment: Can you show the output of  `whatis -2147483647` and `whatis -2147483648` and `whatis -2147483648LL` and `p (long long)-2147483648LL`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `LL` did the trick, but does that means I should never use (cast) with literal ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick And the output doesn't post-fix with `LL` and make me confuse. Is there any way to force gdb output with `LL` if it is long long ?

Comment: Casts with literals are OK, as long as you take into account how gdb does its type inferencing for literals. `p (long long)(int)-2147483648` likely does what you expect, but `p (long long)-2147483648` may not be what you expect, because gdb inferred that `-2147483648` is an unsigned.